# Why does Padme still have a belly even after child birth?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Why does Padme still have a belly even after child birth?

[image]

Here is the picture of Padme's dead body. I believe she gave birth before death. Is she died with baby in her body?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.whattoexpect.com/first-year/health-and-safety/things-to-know-about-your-postpartum-body/#:~:text=You'll%20look%20about%20six,to%20its%20pre%2Dpregnancy%20size.) answer your question?  "You'll look about six months pregnant when you leave the hospital or birthing center."

Comment: Bit harsh on the down votes for a duplicate. For what turns out to have an in-universe answer too.

Comment: @Jontia - The downvotes are probably because the duplicate question would have come up while they were writing it as a suggested duplicate (which was then ignored).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was to make it seem like Padme's child (which no one outside of a small circle knew were twins) had died with her. If she hadn't looked pregnant at her funeral, Palpatine and Vader could easily have assumed they were alive somewhere.